# ASP.NET MVC3 Client Side Validation Help

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, client-side-validation, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using unobtrusive client side validation for my current application but the problem is that it's not validating all fields but only some of them. First I thought that DropDownLists were the ones omitted by the validator, but after changing those for simple TextBoxes, I realized it's not working either. I really don't know what it is. So, I hope you can give me a hand:

I already have on my Web.Config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

I have the Metadata for one of the classes that is not working properly:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(QuestionMetadata))]
public partial class Question
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "Id")]
    public class QuestionMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Question Type")]
        public int QuestionType_Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Category")]
        public int Category_Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1,Int32.MaxValue)]
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Finally the ViewCode:(Strongly-Typed and receives the ViewModel)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="JsContent" runat="server">
   <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/question-views.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2 class="path"><%= ViewRes.Question.Create.PathCreate %></h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
            <div>
               <%: ViewRes.Question.Create.DropDownQuestionnaires %>
               <%: Html.DropDownList("Questionnaire_Id", Model.questionnairesList, "--Select--")%>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.question.Category_Id)%>
            </div>            
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.question.Category_Id, Model.categoriesList, "--Select--")%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question.Category_Id)%>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.question.QuestionType_Id)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.question.QuestionType_Id, Model.questionsTypeList, "--Select--")%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question.QuestionType_Id)%>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.question.Text)%>
            </div>            

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.question.SortOrder)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.question.SortOrder)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question.SortOrder)%>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="<%: ViewRes.Shared.CreateButton %>" />
            </p>
    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Code generated for fields not validating properly:    `code` <div class="editor-label">
     <label for="question_Category_Id">Category</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select id="question_Category_Id" name="question.Category_Id"><option value="">--Select--</option>
         <option value=""></option>
        </select>
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="question.Category_Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

Comment: Code generated for fields not validating properly: `code` <div class="editor-label">
     <label for="question_QuestionType_Id">Question Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select id="question_QuestionType_Id" name="question.QuestionType_Id"><option value="">--Select--</option>
         <option value="1">Selection Answers</option>    
         <option value="2">Text Answers</option>
        </select>
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="question.QuestionType_Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

Comment: Looks that both Question and Category are *not* validating, correct (I thought you said elsewhere that one is validating... Here is what should be generated for select (that is required and numeric):
    <select name="CourseID" id="CourseID" data-val-required="The CourseID field is required." data-val-number="The field CourseID must be a number." data-val="true" class="input-validation-error"><option value="">Choose...</option>

Your Question class is partial... this assumes that you have another file (probably generated by EF) hat has the same values as your metadata class...

Comment: Yes, Question is a partial class since there is another generated with LINQ. But I still don't see any error... I mean, I know the generated code is wrong but I don't see why is that happening. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your properties nullable? 
`public int? Category_Id { get; set; }`

Comment: How come? I don't understand how could this help. Anyway, I tried and nothing happened... Any other ideas?

Comment: I've had the issue where if I don't make it nullable it posts a 0 for the int so the required validator never goes off since it's always getting a value.

Comment: Since you're using unobtrusive javascript, did you include the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js file?

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the tip. However, my problem here is with two dropdownlists that are not validating. If you review the code again, you'll notice that there are two DDL: Question_Id & Category_Id, both of them are declared as required on the Metadata, but still, the validator doesn't act properly over them. =(

Comment: I tried what you told me. Made the field nullable and then changed the dropdownlist for a textbox. When doing so it validates the field as required, if I use dropdow, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you inserting core Jquery script in you Layout?

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you can also use Firebug to see if there is a script error throwing up during validation.

Comment: Yes, I inserted it on the Master Page. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at HTML that is generated. For all fields that will undergo client-side validation you will see something like

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Text field is required." id="Text" name="Text" type="text" value="blah-blah" /&gt;
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Text" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Then it's easier to troubleshoot: is the problem that validation code isn't generated, or that validation doesn't happen, or (as would be in your example with Text field, validation *does* happen, but you don't have `Html.ValidationMessage()`, so error never shows up...

Comment: Hey! I'm using Html.ValidationMessageFor(). It works for most of the fields but sometimes it doesn't. The HTML code is not generating properly as you said, but why? I don't know...

Comment: can you put more details? for code that is not generated properly - what code *is* generated? What do you have for that item in model class (what dataannotations attributes)?

Comment: I already posted the generated code as well as the Validation Model.